# Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='test']

Tags: sxa, package-designer

When I try to make a `package` from `package designer`, I am getting this error `Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='test']`.

I may know why this happens, and the reason for that is that my other colleagues that were working on the project, made a database just for test, and it looks like when they made a new environment they copied the entire configuration from that environment to this new one, and now I have a problem, because I do not have a test database on this new environment.

Is there any way that I can delete this configuration beacuse I do not need this database now? Because this is a test database. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check test database related configuration from this url:

`https://<sitename>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` in your browser.

You can check `showconfig` file through Content Editor as well :

To view the configuration:

1. Log in to `Sitecore` with an administrator account.
2. Open the Control Panel.
3. In the Administration section, click Administration Tools.
4. To see the current configuration, click Show Config.

You have to search for the following string:

`<database id="test"`

This will allow you to identify which config file the configuration node comes from eg.

```
<database id="test" ... patch:source="Configuration.File.You.Are.Lookin.For.config">
```

If you find any configuration related to test database then try to find it in configuration files(.config) under webroot path:

```
 ....\websitename\App_Config\Include
```

and delete them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135490/discussion-on-answer-by-ashish-could-not-find-configuration-node-databases-data).

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot open `showconfig.aspx` page, you can compare `Include` folders to identify all files which are not part of the default `Sitecore` installation or are different from originals.

You can use following applications:

- WinMerge
- Total Commander

Get `Include` folder from fresh `Sitecore` installation and copy it somewhere on your disk. Get `Include` folder from your `Sitecore` instance and copy it to the same folder.

Now using any of the folder diff tools, identify the differences between those two folders. You can search for `<database id="test"` in those files.

Alternatively you can do a full text search on your `Include` folder using Total Commander (Alt + F7) and search for `<database id="test"`.

You can either delete the configuration entry or disable the configuration file by changing extension.

### Update

It is also possible that the change has been made directly in the `Sitecore.config` file which is located in `App-Config` folder. If you cannot find anything inside `Include` folder, please check entire `App_Config` folder.

### Update 2

As I understand, when you are trying to run a showconfig.aspx you get the exception. In that case you can use a tool to build the effective configuration that Sitecore would have build (eg. https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Config-Builder or https://github.com/ParTech/ScShowConfig) and then try to search for the problematic database.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will try to do this

Comment: @Samke11 Please check my update, technically this change can also be made directly in the Sitecore.config file in App_Config folder on level above the Include

Comment: I checked the Sitecore.config file and everything else, still I can not find anything related to the database `test` and I still receive this error from Sitecore, even when I open the page in `preview mode`. I only need to package the items, but I can not do that with this error

Comment: @Samke11 I have updated my answer with another approach, but I have another question: does it happen on all of your environments? Where are you searching for the configuration entry? On your codebase (the one that is versioned in git) or in the IIS folder.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see this error message, generally, something is trying to call a Database that is NOT defined in the Sitecore configuration.

Here are some examples:

1. If your code is calling `Database.GetDatabase("test")` and "test" is not configured in Sitecore configuration, you'll get this error.
2. If in your `ConnectionStrings.config`, you have a database with an id of `test`, you'll get this error message on Sitecore startup.

The way to fix this is to search for the database that it's trying to connect to within configuration, code, or items, and remove the reference to the nonexistent database configuration.

OR, add in database configuration to allow `test` to be a configured Sitecore database.